# Overcome TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) Error for python code

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have tried code on GeeksforGeeks which is giving TLE error while submitting.

**Here is the question:**
Geek is given an array of **nums** of length **n** and two integers **x** and **y**. Geek is interested to find the total number of pairs (i,j) such that x <= a[i]*a[j] <= y (1<=i<j<=n).
Help the geek to find total number of such pairs.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums[] = {5,3,7,9,7,9,7,7},                                                                
x = 7, y = 19  
Output: 1   
Explanation: There is only one pair which
satisfies the given conditions. The pair is
(1,2).
```

Example 2:

```
Input: nums[] = {3,5,5,2,6},                                   
x = 8, y = 13                                                                          
Output: 3  
Explanation: Pairs which satisfiy the given
conditions are (2,4), (3,4), (4,5).
```

**Constraints:**

```
1<=n<=10^4   
1<=nums[i]<=10^4      
1<=x<=y<=10^8
```

**Here is my code:**

```
class Solution:
    def TotalPairs(self, nums, x, y):
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                if x <= nums[i]*nums[j] <= y:
                    count += 1
        return count


#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    T=int(input())
    for i in range(T):
        n, x, y = map(int, input().split())
        nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
        obj = Solution()
        ans = obj.TotalPairs(nums, x, y)
        print(ans)
# } Driver Code Ends
```

**Output after submission:**
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTime Limit Exceeded

Your program took more time than expected.
Expected Time Limit 7.60sec
Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.

Comment: Follow the hint!

Comment: That's the whole point of this exercise - to write code using more efficient algorithm

Comment: Try searching on GeeksforGeeks for the same question. There might be an article explaining how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an O(N^2) solution.

Here's what I think you can do, without trying to give away much of the code since it's an exercise after all.

Essentially, for each number `num` in the array, 
you need to find how many numbers exist in the array which are in the range `[ceil(x/num), floor(y/num)]`.

Take an example, if x = 7 and y = 19, and say num = 2.

 Then the minimum product that will satisfy the conditions is 8, which is `num * ceil(x/num) = 2 * ceil(7/2) = 4`

The maximum product likewise is 18, which is `num * floor(y/num) = 2 * floor(19/2) = 18`.
So for 2, you need numbers in the list that lie in the range [4, 9].

Does that give you a hint on what you're supposed to do?

You sort the array first.
Then for each num:
1)You find the index of ceil(x/num) and floor(y/num), using **binary search**
2)The number of pairs would be the difference of the two indices + 1.

The complexity for this would be, well you take O(NlogN) time to sort, and then you run through all the numbers which takes O(N) time, for each number you perform two binary search operations, so that's `O(NlogN + 2*NlogN) = O(NlogN)`

Answer (score 1):

With the use of combinations we can reduce O(n^2) to O(n). Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations
import math
class Solution:
    def TotalPairs(self, nums, x, y):
        count = 0
        _x = [a[0] * a[1] for a in list(combinations(nums, 2))]
        for i in _x:
            if x <= i <= y:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Edit: You can also use `lru_cache` to reduce execution time

```
from itertools import combinations
import math
from functools import lru_cache
import functools
import time
class Solution:
    def ignore_unhashable(func): 
        uncached = func.__wrapped__
        attributes = functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('cache_info', 'cache_clear')
        @functools.wraps(func, assigned=attributes) 
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
            try: 
                return func(*args, **kwargs) 
            except TypeError as error: 
                if 'unhashable type' in str(error): 
                    return uncached(*args, **kwargs) 
                raise 
        wrapper.__uncached__ = uncached
        return wrapper
    @ignore_unhashable
    @lru_cache(maxsize = 128)
    def TotalPairs(self, nums, x, y):
        count = 0
        _x = [a[0] * a[1] for a in list(combinations(nums, 2))]
        for i in _x:
            if x <= i <= y:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: Not really. The complexity of combinations itself here would be N choose 2, so it's still an N^2 solution.

Comment: Hmm... true that

Comment: Wrote the idea for an NlogN solution below.